# Cannot Increment Object variable?

Tags: php

So i am trying to increment the $i in the actual call if that makes sense, please look at the code to understand:

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i < 8 ; $i++) { ?>
      <td><img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.6.1/img/item/<?php echo $game->stats->item.$i; ?>.png"></img></td>
<?php }
?>
```

essentially what i need to do is increment it like follows:

```
$game->stats->item1
$game->stats->item2 etc..
```

Comment: `$game->stats->{"item$i"};` - what's about using an array instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8 ; $i++) {
?>
    <td>
        <img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.6.1/img/item/<?php echo $game->stats->{'item' . $i}; ?>.png" />
    </td>
<?php 
    }
?>
```